# What is the difference between Uniform/Storage Buffer and Hitgroup Record data buffer?

Tags: raytracing, vulkan, optix

I have a vulkan ray tracer in which I uploaded my vertices as a single buffer (for all meshes in the scene) as a storage buffer. I have one closest hit shader per way-of-calculating-lighting (e.g. one for a blinn phong lighting calculation for opaque objects, one for blinn phong with refractive properties, one for the disney BRDF). I have one hitgroup record per closest hit shader. I map every closest hit shader to an index, and then in the shader binding table I insert the hit groups according to that map. I set a custom instance index in the TLAS instances and the SBT offset is also used according to my map.

In the shader, I read out the storage buffer to get to the vertex data (for this I jump through hoops - I have an extra buffer that stores offsets into my vertex buffer and all other buffers I have) and it works fine.

Now I was trying to port my ray tracer to OptiX which essentially should work with the same set up, but I came across actually putting data, such as Vertex Buffers, into Hit Group records.

Now my question is, should I change to a Hit Group record setup that utilizes these buffers meant for it (independent of OptiX or Vulkan, as both support this but I didn't know it before)? Are there any performance or other reasons to choose on over the other? As far as I can see, I'd need either a Hitgroup Record per shader - geometry combination such that I can read out the vertex buffer without calculating indices before hand and thus blow up my SBT, or I use the same idea of one giant vertex buffer and have to jump through the same hoops to get to my buffer indices.

So far as I can see in samples, the vulkan folks use storage buffers as I did (I think that's why I went that route to start with) and the OptiX people tend to write Vertex data into the Hit Group records (Nvidia themselves [use](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/vk_mini_samples/blob/main/samples/ray_trace/src/ray_trace.cpp) [storage buffers](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/vk_raytracing_tutorial_KHR/blob/master/ray_tracing__advance/hello_vulkan.cpp) in their vulkan samples and [record](https://github.com/ingowald/optix7course/blob/master/example07_firstRealModel/SampleRenderer.cpp) [data](https://raytracing-docs.nvidia.com/optix8/guide/index.html#shader_binding_table#records) in their OptiX samples).